# Hide images on clicking corresponding button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

index.html

```
<script>
    function hide_image() {
        var show = document.getElementById("showimage");
        if(show.style.display === "none")
            show.style.display = "block";
        else
            show.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

{% block content %}

```
<center>
    {% for post in post_list %}
        {{post.user.username}}
        <br>
        {{post.date_time}}
        <br>
        {{post.content}}
        <br>
        <button id="hide_image" onclick="hide_image()">Hide</button>
        {% for image in post.postimage_set.all %}
        <img id="showimage" src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        {% for file in post.postfile_set.all %}
        <a href="{{file.files.url}}">{{file.files}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <a href="{% url 'comment' post.id %}">Comment</a>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to hide the images when the hide button is clicked but when I am clicking the hide button of any image element then only the images of first element are hiding. Why is this happening? Can anyone explain?

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. `document.getElementById("showimage")` does not magically pick the correct image, it returns the first element it finds. Wrap your post content in something like `<div class="post">` then use `clickedButtonElement.closest('.post').querySelector('img')` to get from the button to the image.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to implement clickedButtonElement.closest('.post').querySelector('img')??

Comment: Here's two ways to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lujbmzke/

Comment: Both methods are working but in the second method I have to click 2 times to hide and show the image. why so?

Comment: I made both methods active, meaning the fiddle adds two event listeners to each button. You're supposed to use method 1 or method 2

Answer (score 0):

in hide_image function use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.getElementById()` then use a for loop or `forEach` to implement if statement

Comment: All the images are hiding irrespective of the post they are attached to.

Answer (score 0):

define an int in the for loop and increment it by one then pass it to the image id and hide_image function to allow the function to identify the selected image correctly
for example

```
<button id="hide_image" onclick="hide_image({{i}})">Hide</button>
```

```
<img id="showimage{{i}}" src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
```

```
<script>
    function hide_image(var x) {
        var show = document.getElementById("showimage"+x);
        if(show.style.display === "none")
            show.style.display = "block";
        else
            show.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your block content, make a different class name in all images with post id. Also pass the post id to the `hide_image function` to catch related images:

```
<button id="hide_image" onclick="hide_image({{post.id}})">Hide</button>
       

<img class="showimage-{{post.id}}" src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
```

then in your scripts, select and make operation for all related images to the clicked button:

```
<script>
    function hide_image(id) {
        var shows = document.querySelectorAll(`.showimage-${id}`);
        shows.forEach(show => {
        if(show.style.display === "none")
            show.style.display = "block";
        else
            show.style.display = "none";
        })
        
    }
</script>
```